# Dictionary of Georgian language with lexical stress?

Tags: georgian, lexicography, stress

I search for dictionary of Georgian with lexical stress, but i can't find online of offline. Perhaps Georgian have any explicit rules for lexical stress which i don't know?

Comment: P Elliot's answer indicates that serious linguistic studies do talk about stress in Georgian, but all the beginner materials either say Georgian doesn't have stress or that there is a very weak stress on the first syllable of all words. I never noticed stressed syllables when I was trying to teach myself Georgian in Georgia but I found the trick of putting a very weak stress in the first syllable when I speak it prevents me from unwillingly stressing some other syllable in the word out of habit. I don't believe stress is ever lexical with two words in a minimal pair distinguished by stress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aronson (1990)](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Georgian.html?id=KRtkAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) gives the following rules for stress-assignment in Georgian:

> less than 4 syllables in word -> stress on 1st OR antepenultimate syllable
>   5 or more syllables in word -> stress on 1st AND antepenultimate syllables

[Robins & Waterson (1952)](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract;jsessionid=0F69CF6C0CBF384097D45250C91DDCA1.journals?fromPage=online&aid=3891588) give an alternative, less compact (but perhaps more readable) set of rules:

> 2 syllables -> stress on 1st syllable
>   3 syllables -> stress on 1st OR 2nd syllable
>   4 syllables -> stress on 2nd OR on 1st & 3rd syllables
>   5 syllables -> 1st & 3rd OR 2nd & 4th syllables
>   6+ syllables -> 1st & antepenultimate syllables

Not being overly familiar with Georgian, i can't speak to the accuracy of each, but i suspect the more recent 1990 reference is the one to go with. So, by way of an answer to your question: **Georgian stress-assignment is partially rule governed**. Applying the rules helps, but since at least one of the rules is disjunctive, stress assignment must be partially lexicalised.